# Why is this JSON refusing to get a response? And fails on a curl http://.... response.json command

Tags: php, json, swift

I am having trouble getting this JSON to output correctly.  I have been struggling with this for a number of days now.

The initial error I was receiving was:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}

This is the output in the browser I get when using the request: 
`http://www.quasisquest.uk/KeepScore/getTotalsStats.php?player_id=2`

> {"Stats":{"totalWins":10,"totalDraws":6,"totalLosses":3,"winPercentage":"52.63%","goalsScored":40,"goalsConceded":30,"goalDifference":10}}

After discussion on here it was mentioned the problem may be php side but I am at a loss to what since even a simple `echo json_endcode ("test")` and taking out any MySQL interference has not worked.

I have spoke my to hosting company who have said everything is fine server-side.

This is the Swift function:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
{

    //communitiesTableView.reloadData()
   let isUserLoggedIn = UserDefaults.bool(UserDefaults.standard)(forKey: "isUserLoggedIn");

    if(!isUserLoggedIn)
    {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginView", sender: self);
    }


     let myUrl = URL(string: "http://www.quasisquest.uk/KeepScore/getTotalsStats.php?");
    var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!);
    request.addValue("application/json",forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json",forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.httpMethod = "POST";


    let postString = "player_id=\(self.playerId)";

    request.httpBody =  postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

    print (myUrl!,postString)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

        DispatchQueue.main.async
            {


                if error != nil {
                    print("error=\(error)")
                    return
                }

                do{
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? AnyObject

                    print (json!)

                    if let arr = json?["Stats"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
                        self.totalWins = arr.flatMap { $0["totalWins"]}
                    print("here: ", self.totalWins)
                   }


                } catch{
                    print(error)
                }

        }
    }
    task.resume()

}
```

Below is the php script:

```
 <?php

require ("Conn.php");
require ("MySQLDao.php");

$playerId = htmlentities($_REQUEST["player_id"]);
$returnValue = array();

if(empty($playerId))
{
$returnValue["status"] = "error";
$returnValue["message"] = "Missing required field";
echo json_encode($returnValue);
return;
}

$dao = new MySQLDao();
$dao->openConnection();

//WINS LOSSES DRAWS AND %

$playerTotalWins = array();
$playerTotalWins = $dao->getTotalWins($playerId);

$playerTotalDraws = array();
$playerTotalDraws = $dao->getTotalDraws($playerId);
$playerTotalLosses = array();
$playerTotalLosses = $dao->getTotalLosses($playerId);

$winPercentage = (($playerTotalWins) / (($playerTotalWins) + ($playerTotalDraws) + ($playerTotalLosses)));
     $newWinpercent = sprintf("%.2f%%", $winPercentage* 100);

//GOALS SCORED

$goalsScoredHome = array();
$goalsScoredHome = $dao->getGFHome($playerId);
$goalsScoredAway = array();
$goalsScoredAway = $dao->getGFAway($playerId);
$totalGoalsScored = ($goalsScoredHome + $goalsScoredAway);

//GOALS CONCEDED

$goalsConcededHome = array();
$goalsConcededHome = $dao->getGCHome($playerId);
$goalsConcededAway = array();
$goalsConcededAway = $dao->getGCAway($playerId);
$totalGoalsConceded = ($goalsConcededHome + $goalsConcededAway);

//GOAL DIFFERENCE

$goalDifference = ($totalGoalsScored - $totalGoalsConceded);

//PRINT OUT

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$arr = array('totalWins' => $playerTotalWins, 'totalDraws' => $playerTotalDraws, 'totalLosses' => $playerTotalLosses, 'winPercentage' => $newWinpercent, 'goalsScored'=>$totalGoalsScored, 'goalsConceded'=>$totalGoalsConceded, 'goalDifference' => $goalDifference);

echo json_encode (array('Stats' => $arr));

$dao -> closeConnection();

?>
```

It has been suggested I run a curl http://... -> response.json but this seems to save a file with 0 bytes.

I am totally at a loss and new to Swift so all help is appreciated.

Comment: 10, 6 must be inside double quotes.

Comment: ah! really? why is that? what about the other numbers?

Comment: @Viswalinga That's nonsense, JSON supports numeric literals just fine.

Comment: Can you update the link? It isn't working. By the way, is the server returning the response with `application/json` content type? The JSON seems correct.

Comment: @RD Shove that raw JSON through a hex editor to see if you have any invisible leading characters.

Comment: I've updated the link to _REQUEST should work now

Comment: @deceze how do i do that?

Comment: Save the response to a file (e.g. `curl http://... > response.json`, or whatever tools you have or prefer), then open that in a hex editor of your choice.

Comment: PHP is able to [decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) the json you posted without problems. Make sure the request to `http://www.quasisquest.uk/KeepScore/getTotalsStats.php?` returns a JSON. Using `GET` and without any payload it reports a PHP error.

Comment: @deceze I typed "curl http://www.quasisquest.uk/KeepScore/getTotalsStats.php?player_id=2 response.json" into terminal and it ran but the file it saved has zero bytes?

Comment: @axiac So am I to use `GET` instead of `POST` in my swift script?  If I do that I don't get any error - but I don't get any response at all from the son.

Comment: No, I just tried to open the URL in browser to see what it returns. Then I tried to run (using curl) the request from your code (with POST) and I also received errors. The swift code expects JSON but it receives something else from the PHP web service. Fix the service first.

Comment: @axiac so in the browser it returned correctly, but in curl it errored? is that correct?

Comment: @axiac - ok i think i'm slowly understanding.  So the problem is PHP based... in my code or something deeper with the hosting service etc?

Comment: @RDowns: post here the relevant PHP code

Comment: @IanBell i've updated, thanks Ian - appreciated

Comment: @RDowns: ok, comment out Dispatch etc. and print data

Comment: @IanBell 152 bytes

Comment: @RDowns: "152 bytes" can't be serialized, you are expecting data with json inside

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127826/discussion-between-rdowns-and-ian-bell).

Comment: @IanBell If I `print (myUrl!,postString)` I get: `http://www.quasisquest.uk/KeepScore/getTotalsStats.php? player_id=31`  Notice the gap after the ?  should that be there?

Comment: @RDown: the gap is simply because you print two things. Anyway, your PHP is returning an error now, please correct it

Comment: @IanBell that error may have been because in php `$playerId = htmlentities($_REQUEST["player_id"]);` was set to `_POST` while I was testing the app.  I have put it back to _REQUEST so can be tested in browser with link

Comment: @RDown: when you have corrected the error, try this code, it is working here with my server and my JSON:

let myUrl = URL(string: "http://www.quasisquest.uk/KeepScore/getTotalsStats.php?")
var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!)
request.httpMethod = "GET"
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
do{
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? AnyObject
 print (json!)
      
            } catch{
                print(error)
            }
            
            }.resume()

Comment: @IanBell - I get a yellow warning with "Conditional cast from 'Any' to 'AnyObject' always succeeds" does that matter?

And then when it's running - fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: @IanBell - I replaced the string you used, adding player_id=2 on the end otherwise it wouldn't know what player info to look up.  Normally this id is passed from previous view controller when the user logs in.  Still no luck though.

Comment: @RDowns: as for the player, I hardcoded player=2 to simplify your code and reduce the noise. The Dispatch part is not usable that way (you should Dispatch that one once you get data and you want to do something at the UI thread level). I don't receive your error, even using your url

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was in this line `let myUrl = URL(string: "http://www.quasisquest.uk/KeepScore/getTotalsStats.php?");` The `?` was kicking it out.

Solved :)